# NUnit & MVC4 SimpleMembership

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, nunit

I'm having a really difficult time creating unit tests for my MVC4 application, using NUnit. Right now I'm just focusing on this one test in particular, which logs a user in OR creates them if they don't exist, and then logs them in. Here is the test :

```
[Test]
public void LoginValidUser()
{
       //Start up the DB connection
        App_Start_DB();

        //Setup our default test user
        string UserName = "LocalTestUser@penrouse.com";
        string Password = "books";
        bool LoginWorked = false;

        //check and see if our test user exists
        if (!WebSecurity.UserExists(UserName))
        {
            //If not, create them
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(UserName, Password, new
            {
                Name = "Local Test User",
                IsPromotional = true,
                IsAllowShare = true
            });

            //Log them in
            LoginWorked = WebSecurity.Login(UserName, Password);
        }
        else
        {
            //This user already exists, just log them in     
            LoginWorked = WebSecurity.Login(UserName, Password);
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(LoginWorked);
        Trace.WriteLine("Login Valid User Result : " + LoginWorked.ToString());
}
```

The problem is that every time I attempt `WebSecurity.Login()`, I get a null reference exception, and the stack trace points to :

`System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(String userName, Boolean createPersistentCookie, String strCookiePath);`

Calling that method directly before the login attempt the does not change the behavior. Thus, I have two questions :

- Is there a better way to go about testing these parts of SimpleMembership?
- If not, is there a good way to override or mock out the AuthCookie so that the login will work when tested in this way?

Any help\insight would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: same issue..... i think simple membership api crashes at {Void SetAuthCookie(System.String, Boolean, System.String)}

Comment: anyone has a solution here?